# How do I make my array objects move randomly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, raphael

According to my Prof, I need to make the dots in dotArray to move randomly. I created a draw function that allocated the xpos and ypos of the dots in dotArray according to xrate and yrate. But when I load the html page, the console window shows an error message that says "Cannot read property 'xpos' of undefined". And the dots do not move. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
    var randInt = function (lim){
        return Math.floor(lim*Math.random());
    };

    // Generate random hsl color
    var color = "hsl("+[0,0,0].map(function(){  
        return Math.round(100*Math.random())+"%"; }).join(',')+")";

    // Qn1. Create array of dots
    var dotArray = [1,100]
    var i = 0;  //initialize array

    // Qn3 Create map function
    var x = randInt(2)  // x is a random number between 0 & 1
    var map = function(x,a,b,n,m){
        // String to link x,a,b,n,m
        return n + (m-n)*(x-a)/(b-a); 
    };        

    // Creates 100 dots
    while (i < 100){
        dotArray[i] = paper.circle(randInt(pWidth), randInt(pWidth), 20)
        dotArray[i].attr({
            "fill": color, // Qn5 Initialize color to a random hue
            "opacity": 0.5,// Qn6 Made the dots semi-transparent by changing its opacity attribute 
        });

        // Initialize position of dots
        dotArray[i].xpos = randInt(pWidth);
        dotArray[i].ypos = randInt(pHeight);

        // Initialize rate
        dotArray[i].xrate = 5;
        dotArray[i].yrate = 5;

        // Draw function to change xpos and ypos of dots according to xrate and yrate.
        var draw = function(){
            dotArray[i].xpos += dotArray[i].xrate;
            dotArray[i].ypos += dotArray[i].yrate;

            dotArray[i].attr({'cx': dotArray[i].xpos, 'cy': dotArray[i].ypos});

            if (dotArray[i].xpos > pWidth) {dotArray[i].xrate = -dotArray[i].xrate;}
            if (dotArray[i].ypos > pHeight) {dotArray[i].yrate = - dotArray[i].yrate};
            if (dotArray[i].xpos < 0) {dotArray[i].xrate = -dotArray[i].xrate;}
            if (dotArray[i].ypos < 0) (dotArray[i].yrate = - dotArray[i].yrate);
        };

        console.log("dotArray is " + dotArray[i]);  // Console msg to keep track of dots in the array
        i++;    // Increment of i at end of loop.

    };
        // Calls draw function
        setInterval(draw, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your draw function, the value of the *i* is always 100. You should move your ***draw*** function out of the ***while*** loop and call it with a parameter to reach individual *dot* 
Edit;
change your draw function to this;

```
var draw = function(){
    for (i = 0; i < dotArray.length; ++i) {
    dotArray[i].xpos += dotArray[i].xrate;
    dotArray[i].ypos += dotArray[i].yrate;

    dotArray[i].attr({'cx': dotArray[i].xpos, 'cy': dotArray[i].ypos});

    if (dotArray[i].xpos > pWidth) {dotArray[i].xrate = -dotArray[i].xrate;}
    if (dotArray[i].ypos > pHeight) {dotArray[i].yrate = - dotArray[i].yrate};
    if (dotArray[i].xpos < 0) {dotArray[i].xrate = -dotArray[i].xrate;}
    if (dotArray[i].ypos < 0) (dotArray[i].yrate = - dotArray[i].yrate);
    }
}
```

this will work in your case with just copy paste, but you also should take that function out of the while loop. that way the same function will not be redefined 100 times in every iteration of the while loop.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate a little bit more? I'm quite new to this, so I'm not quite sure how i can call the draw function with a parameter to reach individual dot. Thank you so much!